# how to get a flexible Ember.js parent layout

Tags: css, ember.js

In an Ember template structure with `{{outlet}}`s, the way to organize layouts is generally like this:

```
resource.hbs
  - index.hbs
  - child.hbs
```

In other words, if I want to use an `{{outlet}}` to render templates from child routes, I also have to have an `index` child route that sits in the outlet when at the top level resource route.

Example:

```
<section id="layout">
  Some layout content
</section>

{{outlet}}
```

Is there a way to *not* render anything in the `{{outlet}}` when I'm in the parent resource route?

My use case is that, in the example above I want `section#layout` to be `width: 100%;`, but when in a child route, and the outlet has content, I want `section#layout` to be half the width.

This may be possible to do with some clever CSS, but I'm thinking I'll need to bind a className to the current route name for this to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to not render anything: don't use index child route. In modern versions, index route still will exist (i.e. you will find it in ember inspector), but without template there will be nothing to render.

Comment: I guess it's more of a CSS question then. How would I make the parent span the whole page when in the parent route and then half width in the child route (with the child spanning the other half)?

Comment: Application controller has a property, `currentPath`, containing current route. I think you may use this property to apply some css-class to your container. If your parent route is not an application route, your may use `needs` (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/) to get access to `currentPath` property from your controller

Comment: You can use flexbox so that when the child element is present in the page it will size accordingly.